# Third-party stored procedure returns value on select and it stops my own stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm designing a Stored Procedure which does a lot of things, some of them covered for third-party SPs that I cannot edit because they're hugely used on other places of the app I'm developing. I'll simplify my code in order to explain my problem a little easier:

My code is the following:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_own_sp`(
    IN my_param INT(11),
    OUT my_returned_value INT(11),
    OUT logger TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SET logger = "echo off";
    CALL third_party_SP(my_param);
    SET logger = "half way!";
    CALL another_third_party_SP(my_param);
    SELECT id_user INTO my_returned_value FROM main_Table WHERE id_param = my_param;
    SET logger = "This is the end...";
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

both third party SPs would be like the following, they don't return any value but they modify some tables and records and then they make a SELECT in order to receive the result in PHP:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `third_party_SP`(
    IN my_param INT(11)
)
BEGIN
    -- Do a lot of magic between tables
    SELECT * FROM secondary_table WHERE id_param = my_param;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I execute my SP, instead of receiving the value of my_returned_param and logger = "This is the end...", I receive the select of third_party_SP (I'm not even receiving logger = "half way!". It seems to me that the execution of my_own_sp stops once it receives a returned value, but this value is the last select of third_party_SP.

So the question is: can I handle the returned select of third_party_SP so I can keep working? or maybe there's another way to call third_party_SP in order to avoid the returned select?

Thank you very very much

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a9ed/1).